# I can't get Babel Optional Chaining Operators to work in glitch

Tags: javascript, backend, babeljs

I am new to coding in the backend environment, and I'm using [glitch.com](https://glitch.com/) to write my code currently. I have a [project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tarabryn-advanced-node-and-express-old?path=package.json:11:71) where I'm experimenting with using `passport` for registering users and logging in. I've implemented a github strategy for passport, but I'm getting an error trying to record the user info in the DB. Basically passing `email: profile.email[0].value || 'no public email'` as one of the options is giving me a null reference error when I try to log in myself. On analyzing the `profile` object, I found that it was missing the `email` field, so I wans to do something like `email: profile.email[0]?.value || 'no public email'`

I've been trying for a couple days to get this to work with `"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.6.0"`I'm trying to avoid `npm` commands for the time being, because it's a bit harder to follow what's happening so I'm trying to install what I need in `packages.json` (although I did try `npm` commands previously and couldn't that to work either).

currently I have the following in my dependencies (I've also tried moving stuff into the devDependencies):

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
"babel-register": "^6.26.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.6.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.6.0"
```

I also have the following in `packages.json`: `"babel": {"plugins": [["@babel/core"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]]},` (I also tried it without any options in it)

That wasn't working, so I added

```
require("@babel/core").transform("code", {
  plugins: [["@babel/core"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]]
});
```

to the `auth.js` file (the file that I'm trying to implement the operator in). I also tried it without the `@babel/core` plugin. When that didn't work, I decided to try added `.babelrc` with the following code:

```
{
  "plugins": [["@babel/core"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]]
}
```

That didn't work, so I thought maybe I needed to change it to `.babelrc.json` and that didn't work either. Based on the documentation, it seems like at least one of those attempts should have worked. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just for your [reference](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/alpine-restaurant?path=package.json:4:15). Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got this working. There is no need to compile the files independently, and honestly, I was having a hard time getting it to work that way anyway. So here's a list of things I found out trying to get this to work.

The `babel server.js --out-file script-compiled.js && node script-compiled.js` `start` script is good for pre-compiling the main script file being served. As there were other `.js` files that `server.js` depended on; however, I had a hard time getting that to work. Instead, the original line I had, `babel-node server.js` i sufficient. Because it compiles at runtime rather than creating an output file, I don't have to worry about coordinating it's dependencies, which also need to be compiled, it's all compiled at once at runtime.

There are two reasons it wasn't working: 1: I omitted the `@babel/node` dependency, and 2: in the process of doing my research, found out that the babel engine itself doesn't do anything, and instead relies on plugins for compiling what it needs to. I already had the `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` dependency, but that was it. There is apparently a whole library of pre-set dependencies called `preset-env` that's included with the dependency `@babel/preset-env`, after including the dependency, I then had to include it in the `.babelrc` file, in addition to the plugin I was actually looking for:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
  "presets": ["@babel/env"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The changes should work with the `.babelrc` file.

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babelcore", "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

However, you are not running the code transpiled by babel as per the below command.

```
"start": "node server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
```

It should look like something like below.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "babel server.js --out-file script-compiled.js && node script-compiled.js"
  }
```

Here I'm passing only a single file to be transpiled by babel

`server.js` => `script-compiled.js`

You can take a look at **Compiling Directories** from [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli).

Also looks like you are depending on some templating engine. You might need to make sure that you use absolute paths for the templates or copy the templates to a location accessible by the transpiled script folder

Comment: Thank you so much for that! so it seems like the babel transpiler is working correctly now (meaning the script-compiled.js was generated successfully), but the optional chaining is still throwing a syntax error in the console. I know glitch uses linting, which I disabled and it got rid of the squiggly lines, but not the actual syntax error itself. I know babel is recognizing the .babelrc file, so I think that would be applied universally, and the file that's actually using the syntax is auth.js. Also, the folder the pug template is in I believe is accessible to all files in the root.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding:

```
"engines": {
   "node": ">=16.x"
}
```

to `package.json` resolved problem